# Django get_success_url with variable arguments

Tags: url, parameters

Cant pass a variable parameter in get_success_url

I was trying the following:
model for center

```
class Center(models.Model):
    CenterName = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
    CenterStr = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    CenterCode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    CenterRemarks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  
    Project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
      return self.CenterName
```

with this model I created the following two views:

```
class CentersListViewSys(generic.ListView):
    model = Center
    context_object_name = 'center_list_sys'
    template_name = 'Procure/center_list_sys.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Center.objects.filter(Project_id=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('CenterName')

class CenterDelete(DeleteView): 
    model = Center
    template_name = 'Procure/center_delete.html'
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('centers_sys', args=Project)
#        return reverse('centers_sys', args='2' )
```

when I call the CenterDelete(DeleteView) everything is ok.
The center to delete is available in the rendered web page.

However, submitting (delete) leads to the following url in urls.py

```
  path('centers/<int:pk>', views.CentersListViewSys.as_view(), name='centers_sys'),
```

which expects an parameter (the id of the related project.
How can I return the an url with the related project parameter

Please advice
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Again after few days of try and error I found a solution to my problem.
I had to change the return code to

```
return reverse('centers_sys', kwargs={'pk':self.object.Project_id})
```

That did the trick.

Ben